# Upgraded Contrib modules & Drupal to 7.14 now SSL doesn't turn green

Tags: 7, ssl

I'm using the latest D7 & securepages. When I took over this website from the previous developer, they had the problem that when they would update "anything" (according to them) it would break the SSL. I didn't believe them, so I cloned the site to a sub domain and updated everything. It still worked. My pages in the shopping cart turned into HTTPS, so everything was good. The only problem is that now the browser address bar doesn't turn green (still HTTPS, though) even though we are paying for an extended validation cert. So now the boss is asking why it doesn't turn green.

I checked the certificate and got the following:

```
Website: www.[site].com <- this is correct
Owner: This website does not supply ownership information.
Verified by: Not specified
```

This wouldn't happen prior to the update. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

I was able to get a full SSL connection again. It was one of my images that I manually edited in one of my template files. So now that I have a full SSL connection again, I guess the question has changed slightly to: Why isn't it green? The only thing I notice when checking the cert is that it shows: *This website does not supply ownership information.*

**For anyone else encountering this issue with secure pages:** In your settings file, make sure that if you have redirections to `www.example.com` or `example.com`, and that you have your `$cookie_domain` set properly.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Drupal question anymore.  You may have better luck at ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it would cause your problem, but [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) requires patches to core.  The two you need are listed on the main project page.  I use 961508-23-32-D7 instead of 961508-21.  I am not 100% sure which version of 471970 I am using (that is just for unit tests, anyway).  Both apply to 7.14, but with some fuzz.

Comment: Thanks for the help MPD. It ended up being that I needed to set my $cookie_domain in settings.php. I believe this was due to my .htaccess settings redirect all urls to www